# Multiple Search in SSRS when using only a part of the field

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

I Have created a stored procedure:

```
@DeviceID nvarchar(20) =''

WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS

SELECT  
amd.BRANDID,
amd.DEVICEID

FROM AMDEVICETABLE amd
where 
left(amd.Deviceid,len(@DeviceID)) in (@DeviceID)
```

The length of `amd.Deviceid` is about 15 characters

In Visual Studio I create a parameter `@DeviceID` and when I am entering e.g  ABCDE ( the first 5 characters from Deviceid) everything is working perfect.

the problem is that I want to put multiple values like
jhmcl*, jhmgd*.

Comment: In the procedure, you need to separate all the values out and run each one against the data.  If you put `jhmcl, jhmgd` in the parameter, it's going to look for something containing `jhmcl, jhmgd`, not each one separately.

Comment: Sonny, from a T-SQL standpoint, you are correct, but in SSRS it allows you to pass in multiple values and it makes your variable act like a table.

Comment: so what is the solution. it is not possible to separate all the values in procedure due to the fact that is hundreds of them

Comment: @Stephan I believe you are correct only in the case of an inline query called in SSRS.   When you call a stored procedure, the multi-valued parameter gets passed to the proc as a comma-separated string and has to be handled as such in the procedure code.

Comment: So @georg9, the solution is in your procedure code to use a split function to create a virtual table of parameter values and JOIN to that table with the LIKE operator to get results.

Answer (score 0):

So I created my own little version of your report and I believe the problem is your LEN() function. I'm surprised it doesn't return an error because it errors out in Report Builder for SQL Server 2014(simple version of SSRS). I would test what your LEN(@DeviceID) is returning. I would bet it's not returning the correct value. Instead you might try this to cover every possible pattern. I don't know how it will work performance wise.

```
SELECT DeviceID
FROM YourTable
WHERE LEN(DeviceID,1) IN (@DeviceID)
OR LEN(DeviceID,2) IN (@DeviceID)
OR LEN(DeviceID,3) IN (@DeviceID)
..
OR LEN(DeviceID,15),IN(@DeviceID)
```